# Pull GitHub Repository into /var/www

Tags: apache-2.2, git, lamp, repository, github

I have a private GitHub repo that I'd like to setup my testing server (LAMP) to automatically pull/fetch the files in the master branch and put them in my web root (/var/www).

Wouldn't it be possible to create a shell script that would cd to /var/www and then run git pull origin master? Could I do this using a CRON job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Create a shell script with something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www
git pull origin master
```

You can store the file wherever you like.
Let's assume in /scripts/
Let's assume it's called getsite.sh

Make sure your file is executable:

```
chmod +x /scripts/getsite.sh
```

Run the command to make sure it works. I'll assume you've already run git init, and setup the repo.

```
/scripts/getsite.sh
```

Assuming it works OK, you can create a crontab entry to run it as often as you see fit:

```
crontab -e
```

You'll need an entry something along the lines of:

```
59 23 * * * /scripts/getsite.sh
```

This would run the script at 23:59 every day.

Read up on the man page for crontab if you need help with it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ***yes--but*** you have a few different options to consider. The basic idea is chaining events together, whether you use git-hooks or rsync and cron or even Dropbox.

For more ideas, take a look at http://debuggable.com/posts/git-tip-auto-update-working-tree-via-post-receive-hook:49551efe-6414-4e86-aec6-544f4834cda3

and

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/website-synchronization

Do a search for git-hooks and push/pull and you should find plenty of info.